# Android App Sign issue with new update: apk that is not signed with the upload certificate

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, app-signing

Recently i have uploaded an app to play-store which is live now and i have enabled app sign in too.  But, when i tried to upload a new build, i couldnt able to find my old key store. So, when i generate new KEYSTORE and try to upload, i am getting error :

> you uploaded an apk that is not signed with the upload certificate.
>   You must use the same certificate.

[image]
Please have a look in my developer console, which has both the upload certificate & app signing certificate.

[image]

How to get the apk signed with same fingerprint and upload to play-store?

Ref: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

> If you lose your keystore or think it may be compromised, Google Play
>   App Signing makes it possible to request a reset to your upload key.
>   If you're not enrolled in Google Play App Signing and lose your
>   keystore, you'll need to publish a new app with a new package name.

Note: Related to KeyStore many questions on stack overflow, but this is some thing related to new feature from Google **"App Signing"** and i m not getting nay suitable answer.

**I have contacted Google and their response is not confirming anything. Please find below message from google.**

> I'm sorry for the confusion, however I can see for your app (with
>   package name: com.wma.foodinns.foodinnsapp), you have successfully
>   registered your upload key with Google and have therefore successfully
>   generated an upload key. The upload key you generated and then used to
>   register is the key you should still have on your side and should be
>   used to sign your APKs when uploading new APKs for this app to the
>   Play Console.
>
> The certificate you can download from the Play Console is not the full
>   upload key, but contains the public key as well as some extra
>   identifying information about who owns the key (for more information
>   on this, please see the definitions listed here:
>   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en&ref_topic=7072031).
>
> Do you still have the key you have created that was then registered as
>   as the upload key on the Play Console?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FInally, Google Helped me to get this resolved. I have written an email describing the issue and then after getting their responce, followed the below steps.

1. I created New Keystore.
2. Exported the certificate for that key to PEM format:

> ```
> keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
> ```

3. Replied to their email and attached the upload_certificate.pem file.
4. Then Google sent an email saying they have updated my keystore and i can use the same after 3 to 4 days.
5. I Used the key store newly generated and them generated the signed APK which was successfully uploaded to Playstore.

   Below are the list of locations needed to update keystore

   1. Local machine
   2. Locked on-site server (varying ACLs)
   3. Cloud machine (varying ACLs)
   4. Dedicated secrets management services
   5. (git) repos

Comment: I have lost the keystore.jks files, so i couldnt able to upload new apk, so i contacted Google and they have explained above steps. Then Google changed the new Key store with their server and we are able to upload new apk :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using [Google app signing program](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423), you can request to reset your upload key. For that you need to contact Google. as shown in the screenshots below:

[image: Contact Us]

Contact Us -> Publishing apps on Google Play -> Application signature certificate & keystore issues -> To request a reset to your upload key, *contact us*

[image: reset upload key]

Comment: I have contacted them alreday and their reply is not  confirming anything.

Comment: Email help is not quick at times, You can [chat with them](http://support.google.com/googleplay/) Monday through Friday, 5 a.m. to 10 p.m. Greenwich Time (GMT) is what I know since I had contacted them once while having android rating questionnaire doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Google Play App Signing, you can just create a new upload key and then contact Google support. See [the documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en), in particular the section "Lost or compromised private keys" near the end of that page.

Comment: I have contacted them and their answer is not confirming anything.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry Siba, but theres not much you can do if you lose your key store. I mean if a method exists, wouldn't that defeat the whole security feature of the keystore system?

I personally have 3 backup location of my important key stores. You are lucky in that your app is probably not too new with lots of users. Simply republish this app (with different package name) and you are good to go. Save the keystone we'll this time.

Comment: Thanks but, app just got 150 downloads with 65, 5 star review in 3 to 4 days.. so loosing it quite disappointing. But thats the last option i have.

Comment: Nice! Those are really good numbers for a fresh app. But trust me when you have an app with millions dl that grows 10k+ a day, you will see the world slight differently :) also you can gain back those numbers really fast so it's not a real loss.